# Unable to create mysql database dump

Tags: mysql, dump

I am unable to create mysql database dump. I have tried all the commands in the below question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858436/unable-to-create-mysql-dump-in-mysql-server-5-6-19

But every time I get similar error which asks me to check manual
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
dump -u root -pmysqlmysql hospital_management -r "c:\hosp.sql"' at line 1

I am trying these commands in Mysql command line and NOT on Windows command prompt. Also I am trying these commands before entering any database in mysql.

mysql> mysqldump -u root -pmysqlmysql hospital_management > hosp.sql

This was the first command I tried, which did not work

Comment: That's not SQL syntax, you are meant to run that _outside_ the mysql command line client. So: _" NOT on Windows command prompt."_ => that's exactly what you _should_ be doing.

Comment: Why are you trying them at the `mysql>` command line? That's not going to work. `mysqldump.exe` is the program you need to run.

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump is an executable, you should not run it in the MySQL command line.

Try the command
`mysqldump -uroot -pmysqlmysql hospital_management > "C:\hosp.sql"`

By reading the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_result-file), I assume that when using `-r`, the file must already exist.